# Kendo ui - Need to show a kendo confirmation modal with yes or no button when deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, confirm, kendo-confirm

- when you click three dots you will see delete pop-up.
- when you click delete it will it will delete.
- but before it getting deleted I need to show a confirmation modal with yes or no button.
- when I select yes it should delete when I select no it should not delete
- can you tell me how to achieve it?
- providing my code below

https://jsfiddle.net/su301f1u/

```or-tag-here
var pai_to_delete = null;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pai-del-menu').hide();
        //$('del-menu')
    });
    $(".pai-del-row").click(function(e){
        var pai_x = e.pageX;
        var pai_y = e.pageY;

        $('.pai-del-menu').css({left: pai_x, top: pai_y});

        $('.pai-del-menu').show();
        $('.pai-del-menu').attr('tabindex',-1).focus();
        pai_to_delete = $(this).parent();
    });

    $('.pai-del-menu').blur(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        pai_to_delete = null;
    });

    $('.pai-del-menu').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        pai_to_delete.remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/5jheaz6w/) with `Kendo Confirm`. Here is the code:

**JS:**

```
var pai_to_delete = null;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.pai-del-menu').hide();
        //$('del-menu')

    $(".pai-del-row").click(function(e){
        var pai_x = e.pageX;
        var pai_y = e.pageY;

        $('.pai-del-menu').css({left: pai_x, top: pai_y});

        $('.pai-del-menu').show();
        $('.pai-del-menu').attr('tabindex',-1).focus();
        pai_to_delete = $(this).parent();
    });

    $('.pai-del-menu').blur(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        //pai_to_delete = null;
    });

    $('.pai-del-menu').click(function(){
            kendo.confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete this row?").then(function () {
                        //if user chose Yes
                //kendo.alert("You chose the Ok action.");
                //$(this).hide();
                console.log("pai_to_delete = ", pai_to_delete);
                        $(pai_to_delete).remove();
            }, function () {
                    //if user chose No
                pai_to_delete = null;
                //kendo.alert("You chose to Cancel action.");
            });

    });

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class = 'row'>
    <div class="pai-del-row">...</div>
    &nbsp;
    <div>Row1</div>
</div><br>
<div class = 'row'>
    <div class="pai-del-row">...</div>
    &nbsp;
    <div>Row2</div>
</div><br>
<div class = 'row'>
    <div class="pai-del-row">...</div>
    &nbsp;
    <div>Row3</div>
</div><br>
<div class = 'row'>
    <div class="pai-del-row">...</div>
    &nbsp;
    <div>Row4</div>
</div><br>

<div class="pai-del-menu">Delete</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues :)

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as adding a `confirm` dialog, if the user presses "yes", you delete, otherwise you don't

```
$('.pai-del-menu').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if ( confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this ?') ) {
        pai_to_delete.remove();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/su301f1u/1/)

Comment: thanks for your reply...is it possible to add yes or no??

Comment: Sure, but then you'd need a custom confirm popup, and add a plugin etc. You can't change the native one

Comment: @adeno I updated with kendo ui but its not working...can you tell me how to achieve it?? https://jsfiddle.net/su301f1u/3/

Comment: I don't really know how Kendo works, haven't used it in many years

Answer (score 0):

You should use sweet alert 2 plugin to display custom modal with confirm button

https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

```
swal({
 title: 'Are you sure?',
 text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
 type: 'warning',
 showCancelButton: true,
 confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
 cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
 confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function () {
   swal(
  'Deleted!',
  'Your file has been deleted.',
  'success'
  )
})
```